# Disk showing as dynamic with Acronis and Easus Clone, but it's actually basic

Tags: hard-drive, disk-cloning, acronis-trueimage

I regularly clone my Dell Inspiron 1525 hard drive  with Vista home premium to an identical HDD through a USB using either Acronis True Image 2010 Home or Easus.

This time when I use it, either I get a message saying the source disk is dynamic and that version of either must be upgraded to clone dynamic.

- C and D on the drive show as basic in Administrative tools
- C and D drives show 70 at 1c2 when using HxD tool in the partition hex table, which is disksecure multiboot – whatever that is.

  The 1c2 values of C and D do not show 42, which is the 1c2 value for dynamic. D is a  recovery drive on the disk, not the CD/DVD drive.

I do not know what it was when the procedure was working. Why would two separate cloning tools read the disks as dynamic when they're not – and if so, where, except for the hex partition table, do I make a change to allow them to clone?

Comment: Do both HDD's appear the same?

Comment: Yes both show basic. What is strange is that two separate software

Comment: Yes both basic, and both software Acronis and Easus show the drive as dynamic...one I could understand but both? I have NO idea where both are seeing a drive that shows dynamic for a process that has worked great for months/years and it not a complex process, I have even tried Clonezilla but I cannot get the linux distro to load properly, not related to the dynamic/basic issue. I have no idea

Comment: If both hdds are showing up exactly the same it actually does mean they are dynamic disks.  Have you tried a recent version of those programs Acronis True Image 2010 is 3 years old.

Comment: Rambound,No I have only tried the Acronis but if they are dynamic why are they showing as basic in disk manager and where is the value in mbr or elsewhere that tell the system they are dynamic

Comment: I am only going off the error message you claim you recieve.  You would not be told the disk is dynamic if it wasn't.